# Delete all data but one column in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Sorry for this basic question.

I am trying to delete data from a worksheet, but I actually want to keep all the data that is in column A. I have worked out how to clear all the rows whilst keeping the header but can't find a way to save the data in column A.

Does anyone know how to do this?

```
    With Worksheets("Data")
     .Rows("2:" & .UsedRange.Count).Delete
    End With
```

Answer (score 2):

The `.UsedRange.Count` will return a count of all cells in the used range, not just the rows.

If I understand correctly, you want to delete everything from B2 to the end of the used range. You can do that like this:

```
With Worksheets("Data")
    .Range("B2", Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count, .UsedRange.Columns.Count)).ClearContents
End With
```

Comment: This works great for the OP but wouldn't work in the unlikely event that the UsedRange didn't start in A1.

Comment: @D_Bester, my answer was for the question, specifically for showing how to use `.UsedRange`, not for any possible scenario imaginable.

Answer (score 2):

another way to achieve is as below

```
Sub test()
    lastrow = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    lastcolumn = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
    Range("B2", Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn)).Delete
End Sub
```